# Linking .lib from visual studio on cygwin

Tags: c++, c, linker, cygwin, .lib

I'm porting a Linux project (A) on Windows platform using Cygwin.

I got a `.lib` file from visual studio (compiled with Intel C++ compiler)
that the library is another Linux project which the project A uses.

The compile was a success but I couldn't proceed ld.
When I tried nm on the library, all the required symbols existed in that file.
But the ld with a -L configuration for that library results in the following errors:
`undefined reference to ~`

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You generally can't link libraries from one compiler to another. If you want to link this library that you built in VS, the best way to do so would be by building it inside cygwin.